# How to load a module from a separate `include` directory?

Tags: typescript, webpack

My project's `tsconfig.json` contains this ...

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "generated**/*"
]
```

There are two files `src/main.ts` and `generated/data.json`

I would like to `import data from 'data.json';` within `src/main.ts`. I can only make it work if `generated/data.json` is moved to `src`.

I am using `webpack` and `ts-loader` to output a bundle.

I have tried both using `rootDirs` and path mapping in `tsconfig` so that `src/main.ts` can `import data from`data.json;`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If your `import` statements contain no relative specifiers (i.e., is just something like `import data from "messages.json"`), you will ONLY look in `node_modules` if your `"moduleResolution"` is `"Node"` (which is the most common).

I think a good solution for you might be to use the path mapping feature of the compiler (described here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html). You can then import your data using `import data from 'generated/messages.json'` if you set up the path mapping for `generated` to point wherever you want. That way you can avoid using the relative specifiers if that is what you want to avoid.

If that doesn't give you what you want, I'd recommend parsing through here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html as that will give you basically all your options (unless you want to use a more complicated build system like webpack).

Comment: Alas I _am_ using `webpack`. Possibly this explains why both path mapping, and `rootDirs` had no effect. I shall update & refocus the question.